# SCP requires user to have home directory?

Tags: scp

I was doing this:
`scp aaa.txt $user@$server:~/my-folder/aaa.txt`
and it works.

I need something more "common" so i decided to create a specific user and to use a folder in the root path.
`scp aaa.txt devuser@$server:/folder/aaa.txt`
I receive this error:

> Could not chdir to home directory /home/devuser: No such file or directory

I created `devuser` without the home directory (*-M* option of useradd) but I want the scp to save the file in the */folder* directory that exists and has "devuser" as owner.
I don't understand the error.
SCP can save only on the home directory?
SCP always requires the home directory?

I'm executing SCP from PowerShell but I don't thinkl it's relevant.

### [EDIT]

I created the */home/devuser* folder with `sudo mkdir /home/devuser`, so not the user home and the owner is *root*, and the *scp* command works.

Comment: why not just make that directory the users home dir?

Comment: Please answer your own question, rather than making an edit. Self-answer is encouraged. Distinguishes questions from answers, and you can accept the solution you came up with.   https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH requires users to have a home directory, as [child processes are chdir to their home](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_9_0_P1/session.c#L1623) as as a part of setting up a sane environment. Exceptions include when using `ChrootDirectory`

Create and set a home directory for this user. They do not need write access, if you wish to reduce clutter and enforce that files are stored somewhere not in home.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Especially to point to the exact point where code use _chdir_!